# How to deal with encryption file while using Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop

I have a windows service to convert file from user's upload.But I found sometimes the service will get stuck,the fill make service stuck is encrypted,when I debug it I found program get no response from this line while the file is encrypted:

```
doc = newApp.Documents.Open(ref Source, ref Unknown, ref readOnly,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);`
```

And I have tried to set a wrong password and expected an exception,but it still get stuck from same place:

```
object testPassword = "123";
doc = newApp.Documents.Open(ref Source, ref Unknown, ref readOnly,
                ref Unknown, ref testPassword, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown);`
```

I guess it might be the password dialog block the current thread(when open the encryption file directly it will show),so I tried to catch and close it by using windows api:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll ", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("User32.dll ", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam);
```

And I using an other thread to monitor the 'Password' dialog,as soon as it shows,close it.

```
  IntPtr passworHwnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, null, "Password");
   if (passworHwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
   {
      //0x0010 is  WM_CLOSE value
      SendMessage(passworHwnd, 0x0010, IntPtr.Zero, "0");
   }
```

But I found when I open file in program,it will show no 'Password' dialog because the word process is invisible and the dialog is invisible too so the windows api can't get 'Password' dialog.

Please give me some advises.

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Comment: I know.But it's very difficult to find another free and generic components like office-interop.Do you have any suggestion about office components ?